# Cannot get media stats VLC

Tags: go, vlc, libvlc

I'm using VLC's libvlc-dev library to get a video's media stats but not able to get information regarding the same. I'm using Go's cgo functionality to interact with VLC (3.0.8) I get the following error -

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7fa0e03ad78f]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4ece85, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:378 +0x47c

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4ab660, 0xc000047e40, 0x45eeac)
...
```

My `vlc.go` file looks like this -

```
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -lvlc
//#include <vlc/vlc.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

type Vlc struct {
    instance *C.libvlc_instance_t
    player   *C.libvlc_media_player_t
    media    *C.libvlc_media_t
}

type libvlc_media_stats_t struct {
    iReadBytes    int
    fInputBitrate float64
    iDemuxReadBytes     int
    fDemuxBitrate       float64
    iDemuxCorrupted     int
    iDemuxDiscontinuity int
    iDecodedVideo int
    iDecodedAudio int
    iDisplayedPictures int
    iLostPictures      int
    iPlayedAbuffers int
    iLostAbuffers   int
}

...

// Media stats.
func (vlc *Vlc) Stats() error {
    // fmt.Println("vlc")
    var stats *C.libvlc_media_stats_t
    err := C.libvlc_media_get_stats(vlc.media, stats)
    fmt.Println(err)
    return vlc.getLastErr()
}
```

How can i get the Media Stats ?

Comment: Also, you have to pass a pointer of allocated object, not just dead one; read the docs. Not `*C.libvlc_media_stats_t` but `C.libvlc_media_stats_t`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please explain the same? new to this.

Comment: For the first question, I have no enough context from you. For the second: https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga9057ada11e176f4e2b5b5f529edad076 here's doc, that say `this structure must be allocated by the caller` it means that you have to 1) allocate object 2) pass its pointer. What you do in code above: 1) allocate pointer 2) pass this (nil) pointer

Comment: Oh yes, my bad sorry about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go-vlc has similar code

```
func (this *Media) Stats() (*Stats, error) {
    if this.ptr == nil {
        return nil, os.EINVAL
    }

    var c C.libvlc_media_stats_t

    if C.libvlc_media_get_stats(this.ptr, &c) != 0 {
        return nil, checkError()
    }

    return &Stats{&c}, nil
}
```

stats.go definition is here https://github.com/egelmex/go-vlc/blob/master/stats.go